# Bokeh tool tip displaying all the values for the line

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, hover, bokeh

I am trying to plot a line chart which includes tooltip, but the code below results in displaying all the values of the line in a tooltip  instead displaying a single value for those co ordinates

```
#Import the library
import pandas 
import itertools
import bokeh
import MySQLdb
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

TOOLS='hover'

wells=['F1','F2','F3','F4','F5','F6','F7','F8','F9','F10','F11','F12','G1','G2','G3','G4','G5','G6','G7','G8','G9','G10','G11','G12']

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=640,x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS)

p.title.text = 'Click on legend entries to hide the corresponding lines'
 # Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","password","db" )

#pallete for the lines
my_palette=bokeh.palettes.inferno(len(wells))

#create a statement to get the data
for name, color in zip(wells,my_palette):
    stmnt='select date_time,col1,wells,test_value from db where wells="%s"'%(name)

#creating dataframe
    df=pandas.read_sql(stmnt,con=db)

    p.scatter(df['date_time'], df['test_value'], line_width=2, color=color, alpha=0.8, legend=name,)


    #Inserting tool tip
    hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
    hover.tooltips = [("Wells","@wells"),("Date","@%s"%(df['date_time'])),("Values","@%s"%(df['test_value']))]
    hover.mode = 'mouse'

#Adding a legend 
p.legend.location = "top_right"

output_file("interactive_legend.html", title="interactive_legend.py example")

show(p)
```

Given below is the resultant screenshot
[image]

I am trying to get only one well,Date_time,Test_value at given mouse over instance

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
hover.tooltips = [
    ("Wells","@wells"),
    ("Date","@%s"%(df['date_time'])),
    ("Values","@%s"%(df['test_value']))
]
```

Does not do what you think. Let's suppose `df['date_time']` has the value `[10, 20, 30, 40]`. Then after your string substitution, your tooltip looks like:

```
("Date", "@[10, 20, 30, 40]")
```

Which exactly explains what you are seeing. The `@[10` part looks for a column named `"[10"` in your ColumnDataSource (because of the `@` in front). There isn't a column with that name, so the tooltip prints `???` to indicate it can't find data to look up. The rest `20, 30, 40` is just plain text, so it gets printed as-is. In your code, you are actually passing a Pandas series and not a list, so the string substitution also prints the `Name` and `dtype` info in the tooltip text as well.

Since you are passing sequence literals to `scatter`, it creates a Column Data Source for you, and the default names in the CDS it are `'x'` and `'y`'. My best guess, is that you actually want:

```
hover.tooltips = [
    ("Wells","@wells"),
    ("Date","@x"),
    ("Values","@y")
]
```

But note that you would want to do this *outside* the loop. As it is you are simply modifying the same hover tool over and over.